# jquery: traversing and selecting the child of first element in sibilings classes

Tags: jquery

If I had

```
<span class="test1"><span class="first">first</span></span>
<span class="test1">lorem</span>
<span class="test1">lorem</span>
<span class="test1">lorem</span>

<span class="test2"><span class="first">first</span></span>
<span class="test2">lorem</span>
```

how do I select only the `.test1 .first`, hovering any and only those `.test1` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.test1').hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.test1:first').children('.first').css('color', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you use this as the hover function for test2, or if there are any elements at all before the test1 spans. siblings(':first') won't match the right elements.

Comment: The question specifies that it should work only "when hovering any and only those .test1 elements". As for selecting the children of other siblings, it's not clear from the question that was desired either: "the child of the first element in the sibling's classes".

Answer (score 0):

To get the first span element within a set of elements of the test class, the syntax is like this:

```
$('span:first', $('.test1'))
```

Or for the first element of the class first . . .

```
$('.first:first', $('.test1'))
```

For a hover function you could do something like this:

```
$('span').hover(function() {
    var element = $('.first:first', $('.'+$(this).attr('class')));
});
```